# Should we close questions on custom wordlist generation?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Users frequently ask questions on how to generate custom wordlists like [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102703/help-generating-wordlist-using-crunch) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143720/using-crunch-but-using-words-like-chars). They usually have a particular tool in mind (e.g. [crunch](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch)) and list a number of special criteria for the generated words (e.g. exactly one capital letter, three leading digits, etc.). These questions are usually well-received.

I understand that wordlists are used to crack passwords - which is a security topic. But generating your custom one seems to me like a very mundane coding task that doesn't relate to security knowledge in any way. Essentially, these questions are about scripting permutations of some kind. Additionally, the often very specific requirements make an answer unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.

Should I vote to close a question on custom wordlist generation or is there a good reason to encourage them?

Comment: And if they are to be closed, with what close reason?

Comment: @Anders I'd think off-topic because it's not about infosec.

Comment: Unless it involves deciding what rulesets to use for a wordlist, which are very much related to information security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think every single one I have seen is actually a *programming* question and not a security question. I think the red flag is when they are focussed on the desired output and not the tool. ("I want a list like X" vs "How does `crunch` work?").

A fine line we need to walk is the difference between a question that has information security as the core subject and a question that has potential security implications. Wordlist creation tends to be the latter. Questions about `crunch` are the former.

Comment: So I guess the close reason would be "Not about IS as defined in the help center"?

Comment: @Anders yes, or migrate to SO

Comment: On the other hand, if it focuses too much on the tool vs the actual effect - e.g. what type of password policies, entropy, etc - it might be more appropriate for SU.